# Dynamic Obstacles in AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I am modelling a crowd simulation in AnyLogic where the people throng around a vehicle which moves in time. Since the vehicle is an obstacle, pedestrians should not get within it.

[As walls are treated as obstacles in AnyLogic](http://www.anylogic.com/anylogic/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/markup/Walls.html), I decided to use walls for defining the vehicle.

However the problem is walls are static elements and their position cannot be changed at run-time. So is there any solution or a viable alternative for the problem described ?

**UPDATE**

If I model the vehicle as a pedestrian instead and use a large diameter, peds still manage to get inside it. Moreover, since vehicle is now a type of pedestrian its movement is not straight, and deviates from its path due to collision with others peds.

[image: Image attached]

Comment: Are your people Pedestrians? I've heard -- although haven't confirmed -- that it's possible to say how much space Pedestrians take up, which makes them act as solid objects that others can't pass through. Is it possible to make the vehicle another Pedestrian?

Comment: @DylanKnowles Thanks for your reply, but the problem persists.

Comment: I found that making your pedSource and vehicleSource go into the same "go to" causes them to bounce off one another. It's not perfect, but maybe it'll do what you're after?

Answer (score 1):

If you make `pedSource` and `vehicleSource` both flow into a single `pedGoTo`, the Agents they produce will bounce off one another regardless of their type.

Comment: Indeed they bounce off each other. But the effect is limited within a very small area around the center of the moving vehicle. Increasing the diameter, within `PedSource` has no effect whatsoever. Anyways, thanks for your research.

Comment: Strange -- I found that increasing the diameter in both of the `PedSources` made my cars and people bounce. Have you contacted AnyLogic about it? There's also a LinkedIn AnyLogic group. Perhaps you'll have luck asking your question there?

Comment: I have already asked the question there. [A different method of modelling was suggested](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/Crowd-simulation-moving-obstacles-1524407.S.5973381510554742787)

Comment: Which version of anylogic are you using ? Mine is version 7.1.2

Comment: I'm using 7.1.2 as well.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that pedestrians are placed inside the car (the car is square, and pedestrians are round, so it will take several pieces to cover the entire car), but their speed is zero. Then these pedestrians are placed in the delay block. When the car is moving, you trigger an event with the desired frequency, which each time calls the stopdelayAll function for the delay block or something like that. Pedestrians then enter the pedEnter block, where you can set coordinates for incoming pedestrians - the necessary coordinates are the coordinates of the car. After the pedEnter block, pedestrians enter the previous delay block, in which pedestrians wait for a new event call, and everything repeats. Thus, the speed of pedestrians inside the car is zero, and they do not "bounce" off other pedestrians, and the event with the right frequency ensures the movement of these pedestrians according to the behavior of the car, despite the fact that their speed is zero.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).